Where can i access online or pdf version of this Shiv Mahapuran in simple Hindi, refer picture attatched
Hi I am looking for this puran softcopy or online or pdf version as I am much interested to read this.

But you didn't attach any pic?

Here is the online links for Shiva Puran - Hindi Tranlsation

Sankshipt Shiv Puran With Illustration Gita Press
SHIV PURAN HINDI शिव पुराण हिंदी

